# python class that uses a list prints out address location

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently new to programming and I would really appreciate that someone would clarify why I am getting the print result as a some type of location address instead of the values of the list.I am using **python version 2.7**
also, I tried to override the `<` operator inside this class and it seems to work properly as intended with the instances of the class, but again when I tried to sort the `list` variable containing items of instances of the defined class it prints out location addresses I guess, is it related to the same issue from before, and why it does that, I would appreciate it if someone would provide me with fix for this.

```
a=[0,4,100,4,200,3,300,3.2,400,2]
b=[0,4,150,2.5,300,3,450,2.4,600,2]
c=[0,4,150,2,300,3,450,2.4,600,2]
class subs():
    def __init__ (self,vals):
        self.vals=vals
    def __lt__ (self,other):
        return min(self.vals[1:])-(self.vals[-2]
        -self.vals[self.vals.index(min(self.vals[1:]))-1]+1)<min(other.vals[1:])
        -(other.vals[-2]-other.vals[other.vals.index(min(other.vals[1:]))-1]+1)
sub1=subs(a)
sub2=subs(b)
sub3=subs(c)
allsubs=[sub1,sub2,sub3]
print allsubs
allsubs.sort()
print allsubs
```

This is what i get:

```
[<__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A148>, <__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A288>, <__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A328>]

[<__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A328>, <__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A288>, <__main__.subs instance at 0x05E4A148>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default *representation* of a instance.

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo at 0x3df6908>
```

As Python doesn't know what's important enough about your object's implementation that you want to make visible, it fall backs on a default representation that displays the object's class and memory position.

To have a custom representation, your class needs a `__repr__` method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FOO'

>>> Foo()
FOO
```

For your specific instance, you could possibly get away with just returning `self.vals` and relying on the standard representation behaviour for `list`, although it's probably good form to indicate the class to avoid confusion:

```
class Subs(object):
    def __init__(self, vals):
         self.vals = vals
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Subs({})'.format(self.vals)

>>> s = Subs([1,2,3])
>>> s
Subs([1, 2, 3])
```

(As a side note, your class isn't derived from `object`, which means it's an "old-style" class under Python 2.x. Unless you *absolutely* know what you're doing, you should usually be inheriting from `object` and using new-style classes where possible.)

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
sub1=subs(a)
sub2=subs(b)
sub3=subs(c)
```

You're not actually calling any methods within your class, you're creating an instance of the class. sub1, sub2, and sub3 are subs() classes, and that's just what your output is telling you. Assuming you want to call **lt** in the subs() class, you should have

```
sub1=subs(vals).__lt__(other)
sub2=subs(vals).__lt__(other)
sub3=subs(vals).__lt__(other)
```

Replacing 'vals' and 'other' with whatever they need to be. (Sorry if this should be obvious, I tl;dr-ed a little bit on the code).

Answer (score -1):

You are not sorting and printing lists, you are sorting and printing objects (that happen to have a list assigned to one attribute).  The interpreter does not understand that the list (sub1.vals etc) is the part of the object you're interested in.

One way to solve this is to skip the use of a class and instead sort a list of lists, and use the `keys` feature of `sort()` to specify a lambda or other function to grab the relevant data from the member lists.  I would normally recommend that over using a custom class for this task.  However, if you want to keep the class, then define `__str__()` on the class to specify the string representation of the class.  In this case, something like

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.vals)
```

Comment: ... and, now fixed to make sure the example code actually returns a string object!